# single person detection in latest bodypix

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, bodypix

When I try the bokeh segmentation effect using body-pix@1.0.0, It detects/segments the person (A) in front of the camera. If another person (B) is standing behind, away from A, B is being blurred out. If the person B comes very close to the contour of A, then person B is also getting detected. This is the preferred behaviour.

Now when I try with body-pix@2.0.0, both Person A and B are getting detected even though I am using segmentPerson API. Pls note, person B is standing much away from person A, still both are getting detected. The advantage I see with 2.0 is that the contour of the person detected is much more accurate and smoother than that in 1.0 which had a gap in the contour and the bokeh effect was missing around this gap. In 2.0, the contour is more accurate. But multiple people are getting detected. Is there any parameter I could tweak to restrict this to single person detection and use the smoother contour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to know the answer. Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2547

If you want to use BodyPix 2.0 to only blur just a subset of people (e.g. the large people), a quick way would be to use BodyPix 2.0's Multi-Person Segmentation API: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix#multi-person-segmentation.

This method returns an array of PersonSegmentation object. In your case it will be an array of two PersonSegmentation object: one for Person A and one for Person B.

You could then remove certain people (in your case Person B) from that array and pass the resulting array (with only 1 element: Person A) to the drawBokehEffect https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix#bodypixdrawbokeheffect.

To automate this process for other cases (3 or more people):
Each PersonSegmentation object has a .pose field that contains the 2D coordinates (in image pixel space) of the person's 17 keypoints. They can be used to compute the smallest bounding box area for each person. The person bounding box area can then be used as a criteria to remove small people in the image.